# How to convert hex string "\x89PNG" to plain text in python

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I have a string `"\x89PNG"` which I want to convert to plain text.

I referred http://love-python.blogspot.in/2008/05/convert-hext-to-ascii-string-in-python.html
But I found it a little complicated. Can this be done in a simpler way?

Comment: What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: I don't see any complexity in that way. Just refer the modules' docs used in the snippet. http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: Are you literally expecting it to be 1000 words?

Comment: I'll just have to use the method in the link I mentioned. Anyway thanks guys. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\x89PNG` **is** a plain text.  Just try to print it:

```
>>> s = '\x89PNG'
>>> print s
┴PNG
```

The recipe in the link does nothing:

```
>>> hex_string = '\x70f=l\x26hl=en\x26geocode=\x26q\x3c'
>>> ascii_string = reformat_content(hex_string)
>>> hex_string == ascii_string
True
```

The real hex<->plaintext encoding\decoding is a piece of cake:

```
>>> s.encode('hex')
'89504e47'
>>> '89504e47'.decode('hex')
'\x89PNG'
```

---

However, you may have problems with strings like `'\x70f=l\x26hl=en\x26geocode=\x26q\x3c'`, where `'\'` and `'x'` are separate characters:

```
>>> s = '\\x70f=l\\x26hl=en\\x26geocode=\\x26q\\x3c'
>>> print s
\x70f=l\x26hl=en\x26geocode=\x26q\x3c
```

In this case `string_escape` encoding is really helpful:

```
>>> print s.decode('string_escape')
pf=l&hl=en&geocode=&q<
```

---

More about encodings - http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings