# How to convert hex string to plain text?

Tags: python, file, hex

How to read a **hex** file and convert it to plain text?
 For example,  this is my file [user.dat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5V6UCqZuigkMWR6T2pwN2xoS0U/view?usp=sharing).(For China mainland [user.dat](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1ntJ6zC9))

And here is what I have tried so far:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
with open('user.dat','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
print data
```

And the result is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJha3.jpg).Some is right,while some is not.

How to get the entire right content?

Comment: Do you want to *convert it to plain text*?  Or just print it out?

Comment: Try just open it in `'r'` mode.

Comment: Thanks,but just get the same result above.

Comment: Hmm...see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11683394/5299236) question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547104/convertdecode-hex-string-to-ascii-or-any-other-understandable-format) question.

Comment: And by the way, seems like that there're lots of Chinese and garbled in the decoded string.  Could you upload the file for us download and try to convert it?

Comment: I search on google and stackoverflow,but can not solve it.Many thanks to u! And i have upload my example file. Any suggestion?

Comment: No problem :) Let me check it.

Comment: Unfortunately that I can't print any useful text. I could only get something like `���A�����`. But seems like you've nearly done it. Maybe these text are different encoding?

Comment: That file is raw binary data, not hex.  No hex decoding is needed.  But it's not clear what you actually expect to get from the file:  you said "some is right, while some is not", but you didn't say which parts you think are wrong, or what's wrong with them.  So it's impossible for anyone to tell you what you should do with the data.

Comment: I got the file from my friend,as he can not read the content of it.The right part maybe is the character in Chinese.So i push this question.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

just add this line of in your code, str.decode('hex') will decode string into plain text.

```
output = data.decode('hex')
print output
```

OK you have some error so try this...

```
import binascii
with open('user.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
print(binascii.hexlify(data))
```

Comment: Thanks,but there is ERROR. TypeError:Non hexadecimal digits found

Comment: error can be caused by a content of file(space or some sort of similar content), try updated code